# Unable to get scope in content script Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an addon for Firefox. In a content script file I have the line

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("angularAppDiv")).scope();
```

it returns `null`. However if I type the same line into the browser console, I get the scope object? Could someone point out what's happening and why?

Answer (score 1):

By default, content scripts loaded by add-ons and scripts loaded by web pages are insulated from each other:

- content scripts can't interact directly with page scripts or access JavaScript objects they create
- page scripts can't interact directly with content scripts or access objects they create.

What you could do is to insert this script tag from content script into the page:

```
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + '<script> console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById("angularAppDiv")).scope());</script>';
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts) link for more info.

Comment: i just tried using the unsafeWindow method mentioned in the link you provided but it didnt work? 
window.scope = scope saved the scope. But doing unsafeWindow.scope still logged a null.

Comment: @Irtza.QC It is not possible to use the scope as you try. One thing you can do is manually insert a `<script>` tag into DOM from your content script. See the answer update.

Comment: so basically I want to use the scope in the content script to make a few function calls but you're saying that that's not possible? That if i want to do that I will have to do it from a script I inject into the page?